# DB architecture - structure data

Tags: database, mongodb, architecture, mongoose-schema

I am working on a database structure now and I've faced one tricky moment. I bet it's a common thing but I cannot decide so far what way to choose.

I've got three types of clients - companies, self-employed and retail clients.

All of them have own fields like: firstname, lastname, ... for people and fullname, shortname for companies.

I am puzzled whether I should try to pack everything into one collection - clients and for some of clients some fields won't be available. Or keep them in separate collections.

The pitfall here if I push them all into one collection it would seem messy and when I fetch data I need to pass it to a helper function which detect the type and handles the raw data. That's gonna happen on many pages.

Or if I keep them in different collections I need first detect there to look for the data and have two or three requests.

I believe that's an ordinary situation and there must be good practice on that.
I would appreciate any thoughts and ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Keep them in different collections would be better, like what you said if you push them all into one collection it would seem messy.

You still can use [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/) to make only one request to search those collections.